# How to automate test on reCAPTCHA v2 for Andriod

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, recaptcha

my situation is this: I'm trying to dev some instrumentations test on my android app and can't pass reCAPTCHA (v2 for Android version) on my login screen.

On reCHAPTCHA FAQs (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq) they recomend to configure a test keys pair (*Site key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI / Secret key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe*) for automated tests but when I do that I'm getting following exception: **com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12008: Invalid Type of Site Key**

In short, I don't know what to do here. Any recomendation?
Thanks!